# Vector notation in functions of several real variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Sometimes a function of several real variables is written with a vector $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)$ such that
$$
f(\mathbf{x})=f(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)
$$

In linear algebra I learned that a vector is a vector in the form (with the standard basis)
$$\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)=x_1\mathbf{\hat{e}}_1+x_2\mathbf{\hat{e}}_2+\cdots + x_n\mathbf{\hat{e}}_n$$
Is this the same thing in multivariable calculus?

I.e. I mean is \begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x})&=f(x_1\mathbf{\hat{e}}_1+x_2\mathbf{\hat{e}}_2+\cdots + x_n\mathbf{\hat{e}}_n)\\
&=f(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n) \quad \text{?}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, that is correct. All you've done is rewritten $x$, three different ways.

Comment: True. The point is that $\hat{e}_1 = (1,0,0,\dots,0)$, etc.